# How to explore data from Excel file using GUI with tkinter in Python 3

Tags: csv, tkinter, python-3.7

I need to code a Python programme that uses a Graphical Interface with **tkinter** to choose an *Excel* file and read from it different columns?

Comment: Can you explain better ? what is ?strong text

Comment: @patel - it can be typo. I removed it.

Comment: maybe it will be faster to use Microsoft Office Excel, Apache OpenOffice Calc or LibreOffice Calc instead of writting new program.

Comment: without GUI it is easy to work with excel in `pandas` module.

Comment: You did not explain what you want, I don't understand "read from it different columns"

Comment: I must manipulate  an Excel File extracted from Open Food Facts which contains only drinks I wrote some function to do this but I don't know how to make it wich tkinter so it will be GUI

Comment: here some functions i wrote but I can't figure out how to make a GUI with tkinter  :

Comment: def sugar_level(data,product_1,product_2):
    if product_1 in data['product_name'].tolist() and product_2 in data['product_name'].tolist():
        sugar_level_product_1=data.loc[data['product_name'] == product_1,['sugars_100g']].values[0]
        sugar_level_product_2=data.loc[data['product_name'] == product_2,['sugars_100g']].values[0]
        return [float(sugar_level_product_1[0]),float(sugar_level_product_2[0])]
        [float(sugar_level_product_1[0]),float(sugar_level_product_2[0])]) 
     else :
        error='product does not exist !!'
        return error